# Computer not booting up again after booting up with option key

Tags: startup, recovery

So I was attempting to install OSX snow leopard on my Mac mini from OSX sierra by shutting down and then booting up but holding the option key. If this is totally wrong I'm sorry, but I found it as a tutorial on I-can't-remember-where. Upon doing this it came up with what I believe to be the recovery screen. Anyway, I connected successfully to the proper wifi network, and clicked the little arrow under the "Macintosh HD" drive picture. My computer has been displaying the apple logo on a black screen for 2 days and 2 nights constantly running now. Is my computer ruined? What do I need to do to fix it? Can I fix it?

Side note: I did not change my software version. I am still running Sierra (if you can call it running)

Extra side note: I have a currently not corrupted backup of my computer, that I unplugged properly before this happened and I know it is still fully functioning. So even if everything gets deleted that is ok. I just need the thing to function.

Comment: Which Mac Mini? afaik, the only one that can run **both** Snow Leo & Sierra is the 2010. If you want to just get back to 'where you were' use the Time Machine drive to recover.

Comment: BTW you should see something on the screen after an hour, but if you are booting locally and not off a USB drive or the network no need to wait a day or two. I've sometimes waited overnight but realistically if you don't get anything after an hour, kill the power and try again, or try another approach.

Comment: I believe it is a 2014. However, I thought since it had snow leopard at some point, I could do this option start thing and load into it. Right now it is trying to load Sierra again. I will try killing the power and going again. About the time machine thing. At what point should I plug my drive back in? Do I need to load my external drive instead of my internal Macintosh HD drive?

Answer (score 1):

So, it has finally loaded after a few power kills and restarts. Really hope apple fixes this bug soon. Very annoying.